# disable and enable drop down items in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a UI interface that can disable options from other menus besides the working menu, but then switches enables the options when selecting a different option within the working menu, overriding previous disables in other menus.

For example, if I press '2' in First menu, then all other menus will disable '2'.
If I press '1' in the First menu, then all other menus will disable '1', but now 2 will be enabled.
If I press '2' in the second menu, then now all other menus will have '2' disabled besides the second menu, and all other menus will have '1' disabled besides the first menu.

I tried to make puedo code that tries to depict the logic, though it might not work:

```
- take in I clicked on '2' in First menu.
- check to see if my last click was for in the First menu, finds no previous click, and enable nothing across all menus First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth.
- try to disable '2' on menus Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth, if they have that option.

- take in I clicked on '1' in the First menu.
- check to see if my last click was for in the First menu, finds that I clicked '1' and enables '1' across all menus First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth.
- try to disable '1' on menus Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth, if they have that option.

- take in that I clicked on '4' in the Second menu.
- check to see if my last click was for in the first menu, finds no previous click, and enables nothing across all menus First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth.
- try to disable '4' on menus First, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth, if they have that option.
```

Here is what I tried to do/already have below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox


# Create the Frame and menubar
root = Tk()
root.title('Example Run')
root.iconbitmap('') #None for now, specifying directory on computer
root.geometry("1000x500")

#Create Menu
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

# Create the menu widgets
First = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)
Second = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)
Third = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)
Fourth = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)
Fifth = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)
Sixth = Menu(menubar, tearoff = False)


Menu_Choices = [First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth]
    
# Add menu widgets to the menubar
menubar.add_cascade(menu=First, label="First")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=Second, label="Second")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=Third, label="Third")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=Fourth, label="Fourth")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=Fifth, label="Fifth")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=Sixth, label="Sixth")

# Define the names of each menu
First_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
Second_list = ['2','4','6','8','10']
Third_list = ['3','6','9','12','18']
Fourth_list = ['1','3','5','7','9']
Fifth_list = ['2','3','5','7','8']
Sixth_list = ['END']
menu_list_items = [First_list, Second_list, Third_list, Fourth_list, Fifth_list, Sixth_list]


def disable_menuitem(menu_item):
        enable_all_menus()
        for i, m in enumerate(menu_list_items):
            if menu_item in m:
                menus[i].entryconfig(m.index(menu_item)+1, state="disabled")


# Function to enable all of the menu items  
def enable_all_menus():
    for i, m in enumerate(menu_list_items):
        for j in m:
            menus[i].entryconfig(m.index(j), state="normal")
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please do not duplicated  previously code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935033/python-tkinter-disabling-drop-down-options-across-all-options-even-after-other/74935145#74935145

Comment: Got it, went ahead and deleted that post. I don't think I didn't think I did a good job explaining it as people were getting confused by my wording.

Comment: We are trying to help tp solve problem. Please br patience, it long weekend for New Year holiday.